# What is the easiest way to check if table data has been manipulated in firebug

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, firebug, data-manipulation

I have a table, that obviously has ids for each row. When a user clicks on a table row he is taken to a different page where it shows the full data(The different page is really the same page which is unhid after the load event).

I am picking up the click event with jquery and then sending the id to jquery load and it loads in the data.

The problem is this. If the person using the page has firebug installed he can manipulate the id on the table and maybe access something he shouldn't be accessing.

So I have had to write a function that checks the id coming in can be accessed by that user.

```
function checkID($searchColumn,$userColumn,$tablename,$table_id,$user_id)
{
    Global $db;
    $query = "SELECT `{$userColumn}` FROM $tablename WHERE `{$searchColumn}`=?";
    //echo $query;
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$table_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($myuser_id);

    if($stmt->fetch())
    {
        if($myuser_id==$user_id):
            return true;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;
    }   
}
```

Basically the above function gives me a true or false depending on whether that id can be accessed by the user.

Is there a better way to check if data has been manipulated in firebug on server side?

Basically I want to make sure the id being sent to the server is the same id that is in the table, and not been manipulated by firebug. Even though my function works I keep thinking perhaps there is a simpler solution. What do the professionals do?

Comment: Note that browsers have built-in developer tools nowadays, so the users don't even have to install Firebug.

Comment: I agree. Firebug is an example. I know there are others out there, but I use firefox so firebug is the one that I know. I was looking for an easier method to validate the id than I am using, and was asking what the professionals do?

Comment: Two notes: 1. [Firebug is going away](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/), so at some point you'll have to use the built-in [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools). 2. I provided an answer, though it's still a bit unclear to me how the table actually looks like.

Comment: You should provide an example for your question to illustrate the problem. E.g. it's not clear whether it's the data from the same database table when the user clicks on a row or a details table.

Comment: I didn't provide a table example because everyone knows what an html table looks like. It has <tr><td> and each table row has an id. My problem is that jquery takes that id when you click on a table row, but it may have been manipulated by the user using firebug, or some other way of manipulatoin. I want the easiest way to check if the id has been changed by the user.  The only thing that is important in the above function is the fact it checks if the table id is valid by checking if there is a user in the mysql database corresponding to the table id code.

Comment: I meant an example for your database table, not the HTML table. I've updated my answer to provide an example for how to safely avoid access of data unrelated to a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data coming from the client **always** needs to be validated and sanitized on the server side.

I.e. if `$searchColumn`, `$userColumn`, `$tablename`, `$table_id` and `$user_id` come in as request variables, you need to check each of them for validity. Especially `$userColumn`, `$tablename` and `$searchColumn` need to be checked carefully for SQL injections, because they are added before you call `prepare()`.
If you don't require the flexibility, you should enter the table and column names into the string.

You may even keep the user ID on the server side (as session variable) and only set it once on login, so you can get rid of the check completely. The tables referencing the user data still need to have a column with the user ID, though.

To ensure that a user can only access the data (s)he's supposed to see, you need to include the user ID in the query.

**Example:**

Imagine you have orders and order items in an 1 to m relation. You show the user the list of orders (s)he has made. When the user now chooses an order to display its items you can include the user ID in the query to ensure the user cannot access orders of other users.

Then the SELECT statement may look like this:

```sql
SELECT oi.name,
       oi.description
       oi.price
FROM order_item oi
INNER JOIN order o ON o.id = oi.order_id
WHERE o.id = ?
  AND o.userID = ?
```

When the user then provides an ID of another user's order, there won't be any items returned.

This could also be done in two steps by first making a query against the `order` table to check whether the order is assigned to the user and if so, making a query against the order items.

Comment: The only thing my function is checking is the table row id. I have to pass in the table name and everything else so that my function can check them. Basically when I click on a table row I am taking them else where to see the data, but if they have manipulated the id, they may see data they shouldn't see. As for sanitation I always use prepared queries. The code I have showed is my current function for checking that an id is valid. It works fine, but I was looking for a simpler solution

Comment: I see so using this method if they change the id the query won't bring back any data. I have just been searching by id you see. So in my query I should be searching for id, and user id. Then if they change the id in firebug the query will be empty. Why didn't I think of this

Comment: Exactly! You need to check whether the data is actually assigned to the user. I further updated the answer to note that you can also do this in two separate queries. It might get complexer depending on the relations between the tables, but basically you can always query for whether the data belongs to the user. Sometimes it's not that easy to see the simplest answer. :-)

Comment: Well with this method I do not even need the above function. Stupid thing is that I usually do check username and ids in other places, but didn't think to do it on tables, because at the time I didn't know that an id could be manipulated by the user. Would you believe I have been doing databases for about 5 years not realising that there is big security hole I never even realised. Thanks